# Время в docker (apache)

Tags: django, apache, docker

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl apt-utils apt-transport-https debconf-utils gcc build-essential g++-5\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# adding custom MS repository
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

# install libssl - required for sqlcmd to work on Ubuntu 18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev

# install SQL Server drivers
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev

# install SQL Server tools
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"

# python libraries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip python3-dev python3-setuptools \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install necessary locales
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# install SQL Server Python SQL Server connector module - pyodbc
RUN pip3 install pyodbc

# install additional utilities
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gettext nano vim -y

# add sample code
WORKDIR /app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get install apache2 apache2-dev -y
RUN pip install mod_wsgi


RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install unixodbc \
  && apt-get -y install mc \
  && apt-get clean

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
#change timezone
ENV TZ=Europe/Kiev
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y install tzdata

COPY . /app
#RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT mod_wsgi-express start-server /app/avtosojuz_table/wsgi.py --user www-data --group www-data --url-alias /static static --port 3000
```

Добрый вечер.
запускаю контейнер меняю в нем время,
все гуд, после запускаю apache - у него почему-то не верное время..
целый день танцы з бубном, подскажите что не так

```
docker build -t avto_table .
docker run -p 3000:3000 --name avto_table avto_table
```

Comment: Как запускаете контейнер? Как меняете время? Как запускаете апач? Какими командами, то есть. Это все нужно добавить в вопрос. Так мы не догадаемся, где вы что делаете не так.

Comment: команды добавил в описание

Comment: Что по вашему "неверное время"? Что ожидаете увидеть и что видите? Как проверяете это?

Comment: если подключиться к cli, написать date, оно показывает верное время.
но там работает apache, на котором крутится django, и при вызове datetime.datetime.now() (свойство для получения текущей локальной даты и времени)- 
я получаю время меньше на 3 часа.

Comment: Покажите что он показывает сейчас?

Comment: текущее время : 18:05
на apache: 15:05

Comment: я бы рекомендовал установку пакета tzdata производить в числе первых. естиественно, директивы `ENV TZ=Europe/Kiev` и `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` надо будет вставить ещё выше. а директиву `RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone` вообще выбросьте: она в данном случае не нужна. можете сами убедиться: `$ docker run --rm -ti -e TZ=Europe/Kiev -e DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive ubuntu:18.04 sh -c '{ apt-get update && apt-get install tzdata; } >/dev/null 2>&1 && date'`

Comment: но скорее всего, все эти манипуляции не помогут: вероятно, у django, python, или чего-нибудь ещё из устанавливаемого вами, свои представления о текущем часовом поясе (да, время вам и программа python, и программа date показывают верное, только для разных часовых поясов). см. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: Не помогло, попробовал ваши советы. уже не знаю что и делать... =(

Comment: Проблема где-то в `mod_wsgi-express`, если точнее в том, что он, похоже, имеет свою конфигурацию таймзоны. По крайней мене, если в этом контейнере запустить просто `python3 -c "import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.now())"` то время правильное. python сам по себе использует переменную окружения TZ, а `mod_wsgi-express` похоже ее изменяет, можете кстати проверить запустив команду типа `docker exec CONTAINER_NAME /bin/cat /proc/PYTHON_PROC_ID/environ` когда контейнер запущен.